# Converting a Matrix to a Vector in openCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have an image 16x16 pixel image , how can I put it in a matrix 1x256 pixel and then convert it back to a 16x16 pixel Using opencv ?
I tried reshape but it didn't succeed as when i make cout<< image.cols << image.rows give me the same number which is 16,16 also sometimes the image is not continuous so reshape won't work 
Btw I  need it in coding a neural network classifier.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// create matrix for the result
Mat image1x256(Size(256,1), image.type());
// use reshape function
Mat image16x16 = image1x256.reshape(image.channels(), 16);
// copy the data from your image to new image
image.copyTo(image16x16);
```

Since image16x16 and image1x256 are just different pointers to same data, then copying the data to one of them will actually change both.

Note that reshape function creates a new header (i.e. new smart pointer) that may be used instead of old one, but it is not changing properties of the original header that still exist and can be used.